# Корректно ли расположены придаточные предложения?

Tags: синтаксис, союзы, спп, придаточное-предложение, союзные-слова

Скажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли построено предложение с союзами "что"?
Точнее, указанный фрагмент.

*В обеих жалобах есть пати-лист либо в обычном виде, либо в виде логов передвижений, **что доказывает, что** игроки были участниками фан-игры.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*В обеих жалобах есть пати-лист либо в обычном виде, либо в виде логов передвижений, **что** доказывает, **что** игроки были участниками фан-игры.*

Да, так писать можно (в конце предложения ставится точка).

Первое слово "что" замещает подлежащее из главного предложения (доказывает [что?] пати-лист), это относительное местоимение — союзное слово.

*Длина обоих валов около 500 метров; один вал сложен из крупных окатанных валунов, обросших лишайниками, **что доказывает**, что камни эти давно уже находятся в состоянии покоя* (В. К. Арсеньев. Дерсу Узала).

Второе слово "что" является союзом.

[Союз или союзное слово?](http://philolog.pspu.ru/module/magazine/do/mpub_26_557)

Comment: Вот только стилистика нехороша. А первое "что"  замещает предложение, а не подлежащее.

Comment: Ну да, ну да, нехороша. Но все-таки допустима. Поэтому я и привела в качестве примера *классическое предложение*.

Comment: И там тоже нехороша)  А что с грамматикой?

Comment: Не будем же мы править Арсеньева. Вот еще: *На самом деле он не злился, он играл, что доказывает, что он не был глупым* (Фазиль Искандер. Морской скорпион). И еще: *...нечто такое, что доказывает, что представление о тишине далеко не свободно...* (М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин. Самодовольная современность).

Comment: И что с того? Стилистика от этого не становится лучше, если известные писатели так написали. Самим надо писать нормально..

Answer (score 1):

> *В обеих жалобах есть пати-лист либо в обычном виде, либо в виде логов
> передвижений, **что доказывает, что** игроки были участниками фан-игры.*

Гм… Если бы писал это я, то постарался бы или заменить первое «что» на «и это»:

> *В обеих жалобах есть пати-лист либо в обычном виде, либо в виде логов
> передвижений, **и это доказывает, что** игроки были участниками фан-игры.*

– или постарался бы убрать второе «что». Например, так:

> *В обеих жалобах есть пати-лист либо в обычном виде, либо в виде логов
> передвижений, **что доказывает участие** игроков в  фан-игре.*

**Может, я и не прав.**

Answer (score 1):

Замена **повторяющегося** местоимения "что":

*В обеих жалобах есть пати-лист либо в обычном виде, либо в виде логов передвижений, **а это** доказывает, что игроки были участниками фан-игры.*

**Грамматическая справка**

При замене мы переходим от подчинительной связи (союзное слово ЧТО) к сочинительной (союзное соединение А + ЭТО).

Союзное слово ***ЧТО*** используется в СПП с придаточными присоединительными, при этом оно замещает предикативную основу главного предложения.

Местоимение ***ЭТО*** (как дополнительный структурный элемент при сочинительном союзе А) имеет такое же значение, то есть указывает на предыдущее предложение. Такие конструкции считаются **синонимичными.**